# Can the PHP sleep function be used to mitigate bot traffic?

Tags: php, bots, sleep, bandwidth

I noticed a massive increase in unwanted bot traffic to my login page. I tested blocking IP's, denying specific bots access and also denying all except bots on a whitelist, but all have drawbacks. A captcha is not the solution because bots still use bandwidth. I am now testing a delay:

`sleep(2);`

Added before the rest of the PHP code.

Is this a good way to limit bot bandwidth usage? Any problems with this solution that I have not thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `sleep()` is a good way to ensure you have a possible DDoS attack. Sleep will still keep the thread busy, only your CPU will be freed. This means that your available connection pool will be used up quicker than it should. Such bandwidth or DDoS prevention should be done on the server level not in PHP application.

Comment: Many thanks @Dharman. Apart from DDOS though, if the bot is simply trying to strongarm the login, it looks like the sleep function slowed it down to a point where we don't see 503 errors anymore and guessing the password will now take decades.

Comment: What is meant by "is a good way to ensure you have a possible DDoS attack" - is it ironic? B.t.w. can't php be multi threaded?

Comment: @ValterEkholm No, PHP cannot be multithreaded. Adding 2 seconds to the runtime of your website means that every request will take 2 seconds more. Servers such as Apache allow you to use a certain number of PHP processes and if all of them are busy, the user will have to wait even more for response. That's why adding unnecessary `sleep()` can cause DDoS. I can't see any irony in this.